# Scala date parse with java LocalDateTime

Tags: java, scala, parsing, localdatetime

I'm trying to parse a date like this "2020-07-01T00:00:00Z" with java `LocalDateTime` (in Scala) in this way:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2020-07-01T00:00:00Z", ISO_INSTANT)
```

but I'm getting this exception:

> `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-07-01T00:00:00Z' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor`

What could be the problem here?

these are my libraries:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter._
import java.time.LocalDateTime
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the zone the `LocalDateTime` is related to for parsing.

```java
LocalDateTime.parse("2020-07-01T00:00:00Z",
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

A `LocalDateTime` stores no zone information but it is, abstractly speaking, related to one anyways. Multiple `LocalDateTime`s can be parsed from the same UTC timestamp, i.e. the time offset of the specific (local) zone is added/subtracted.

Don't misunderstand this with `ZonedDateTime`. A `ZonedDateTime` stores zone information, thus it has a 1:1 relation to a UTC timestamp. A UTC timestamp has a 1:n relation to `LocalDateTime`s.

Comment: Hmm... It has never occurred to me that OP would want 2020-07-01T00:00:00 + offset of current timezone as the result. My interpretation is that OP wants to get the local date time portion of "2020-07-01T00:00:00Z", which is "2020-07-01T00:00:00". But I guess yours is also a valid interpretation :)

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, the OP's question is somewhat ambiguous in that regard. But I think if you want a `LocalDateTime` from a UTC timestamp, you probably want it to be in your local zone. If the OP is after parsing just the "local datetime portion" of the UTC timestamp, which is redundant because .. just use the timestamp directly, it'd be `.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))` or `withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` if you want to skip the daylight saving stuff. But I totally agree with your answer that a different parser is semantically better here.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use the `ISO_INSTANT` formatter, because that formatter is for parsing to `Instant`s, while you want a `LocalDateTime`.

You should use another `DateTimeFormatter`. Here are some choices. All of these are "supersets" of the `ISO_INSTANT` format.

- [`ISO_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE_TIME)
- [`ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
- [`ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)

---

Alternatively, parse the string to an `Instant` first, then:

```
instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime()
```